# LeafPHP - Problemas variables de sesion

Tags: php, php8, leaf

Estoy usando LeafPHP para generar una app sencilla de produccion, la cual tiene un login sencillo, el cual recibe los datos desde un formulario y los valida del lado del controlador.

El asunto extraño, es que en el proceso que valida, genera bien las variables de sesion, pero al momento en que redirecciona, estos datos se pierden:

Revise con detalle la funcion que trae Leaf, `auth()->login()` ya que esta es la que realiza el proceso de validar si el usuario existe y la contraseña coincide, luego genera el token y las variables de sesion, hasta aqui todo funciona perfecto... El problema viene cuando en la ultima parte redirecciona a la ruta por defecto definida luego de hacer el login (en mi caso 'dashboard') y las variables de sesion se eliminan o desaparecen ($_SESSION). Esta ultima parte donde sucede es: `exit(header('location: ' . static::config('GUARD_HOME')));`

Lo mas extraño de todo esto, es que si accede de forma local (localhost), no tengo problemas con la sesion y accede perfecto, pero si utilizo la IP externa del servidor, ocurre el problema, y la idea es que la gente acceda al servicio de forma externa.

Como detalle, para esto me entregaron una maquina con windows 10, con xampp instalado y alojado en un ligthsail de AWS (lo solicitaron asi...)

Ya revise firewall, configuracion de php y apache y no se que mas pueda revisar o ser.
Espero me puedan ayudar u orientar.

Comment: y de casualidad no requiere declarar o continuar con sesion_start etc???